# How to make and use makefile winidows Nomad open solver

Tags: c++, makefile, solver, nomad

I use an Open Solver open source called Nomad 3.8.1.
I installed MinGw with g++ and Visual Basic with nmake

I have several directories (build of software/ source code, etc)
In the example provided there are two files (basic_lib.cpp for calculate and Makefile)

However, in the documentation i saw makefile is for Linux
(I work with Windows)

So I updated makefile

```
EXE                    = basic_lib.exe

COMPILATOR             = g++

COMPILATOR_OPTIONS     = -O2 -ansi 


LIB_DIR                = C:/Users/***/Documents/nomad.3.8.1/lib
LIB_NOMAD              = libnomad.so 

CXXFLAGS               =           

CXXFLAGS_MPI           = $(CXXFLAGS) -DUSE_MPI


LDLIBS                 = -lm -lnomad

INCLUDE                = -IC:/Users/***/Documents/nomad.3.8.1/src -IC:/Users/***/Documents/nomad.3.8.1/ext/sgtelib/src -I.

COMPILE                = $(COMPILATOR) $(COMPILATOR_OPTIONS) $(INCLUDE) -c
COMPILE_MPI            = $(COMPILATOR_MPI) $(COMPILATOR_OPTIONS_MPI) $(INCLUDE) -c

OBJS                   = basic_lib.o




$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(ECHO_NOMAD)
    @echo "   building the scalar version ..."
    @echo "   exe file : "$(EXE)
    @$(COMPILATOR) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS) $(CXXFLAGS) -L$(LIB_DIR) 

basic_lib.o: basic_lib.cpp
    $(ECHO_NOMAD)
    @$(COMPILE) basic_lib.cpp
```

Directories src contain .cpp and .hpp

When I run nmake with Visual Basic I obtain the error ld.exe: cannot find -lnomad
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Could you help me ?
 (I don't know what can be nomad...)

Comment: Have you built this `nomad` library?

Comment: It is the first time i program in C++. Do you know the extension of the library ? Is it a directory ? If yes what are the extensions of the files contained ? Have I to place the library in the same place of the makefile ? I found a .sln that I build with VS